# Android second thread error

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading, exception

When I open the activity for the first time, everthing is fine. When I go back, and reopen the activity my app crashes.

Here is my errorlog:

```
07-09 00:11:47.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22799): FATAL EXCEPTION: TIMETHREAD
07-09 00:11:47.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22799): Process: testprogram, PID: 22799
07-09 00:11:47.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22799): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 00:11:47.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22799):    at testprogram.LocationActivity$1.run(LocationActivity.java:61)
07-09 00:11:47.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22799):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is the source:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
timethread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            while(0 < 1)
            {
                text_currentime.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        text_currentime.setText(getCurrentTime());
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_TIME);
            }
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
timethread.setName("TIMETHREAD");
timethread.start();
```

Comment: You're going to need to add more context here for anyone to help. A stack trace (see Android Logcat) at the point of the error, and some information as to how you're using the code above, specifically how it ties into your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` - so I would assume that when you are exiting the app, it is destroying your thread. This can happen in certain situations such as when the app needs to free up memory. When you open your app again, the Activity's `onResume` method is called rather than `onCreate`, so it's trying to reference something that doesn't exist.

So one thing you could do is use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save any variables, then override the `onResume` method and create the thread again.